# Cannot access file from other drive

Tags: c, dosbox

I am using windows 7 64bit OS and DOS box turbo C++. I want to write a simple program to read a text file containing a single integer from E drive of my machine. The file name is `t.txt`. I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    FILE *input;
    int data;
    if ( (input = fopen("E:\\t.txt","r")) == NULL)
         printf("Error: Unable to open");
    else
    {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&data);
        printf("successfully read in %d",data);
    }
    fclose(input);
    input=NULL;
    getch();
}
```

But this program is unable to access the file and every time it gives an output like:

> Error: Unable to open

What is the problem with this code?
Please help.

Comment: Is the path right? `E:\t.txt`? and is file names `t.txt`?

Comment: If the open fails, what is returned by GetLastError()?

Comment: does your program have read-permissions on the text-file AND on the E: device?

Comment: have you tried to chwd() to your E: device and then open just the t.txt file?

Comment: is your underlying file-system case sensitive?

Comment: do not fclose() your FILE * if it wasnt fopen()ed.  [the fclose() belongs inside the else-part]

Comment: _"using DOS box"_. Have you [mounted](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/MOUNT) E: in DOSBox?

Comment: I hope you're using a compiler that's 21 years out of date because you really like DOS, and not because you think it's even remotely a good idea in general.

Comment: #include <errno.h> and printf `errno` which contains number of the last error that occured.

Comment: I don't know how to mount E: in DOSBOX or else. I don't know anything about dosbox. I just downloaded it. Even I want to use any windows version of C compiler. Can you suggest anyone?

Comment: @LSG, when editing, please edit the original question, do not place your code in a comment (also suggest do not write comments to your question, rather edit the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes!!! got it.. Thank you Michael. I tried to mount E: in dosbox and it has run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem must be with the usage of file path

Solution given below worked with me in Ubuntu
just try it

```
char *file = "E:\\t.txt";
FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
```

And verify whether you are using the correct path
Have a good day

Comment: _"Solution given below worked with me in Ubuntu just try it"_ The OP is building a DOS executable and running it in DOSBox on a Windows host. The problem is most likely that the OP hasn't mounted the drive in DOSBox.

Comment: still it is not working. Just have a look on my new code #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dir.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
FILE *input;
int data;
char *filename="E:\\t.txt";
clrscr();
input=fopen(filename,"r");
if(input==NULL)
printf("Error: Unable to open");
else
{fscanf(input,"%d",&data);
printf("successfully read in %d",data);
}fclose(input);
input=NULL;
getch();
}

Comment: I have also checked E drive again.. the file is there containing a single integer 5

Comment: what is OP? and how to mount it with dosbox?

Comment: @LSG: OP = Original Poster (== you).